# Ambiguous reference in swift3

Tags: reference, alamofire, swift3, ambiguous

Hi after migrating to swift3. I m having this issue? Do your guys know what wrong?

ambiguous reference to member "/"

```
let rateForPeriod = interestRate! / Double(100) / Double(K.monthsEachYear)
```

Comment: Type of `interestRate`?

Comment: double type bro

Comment: it seems error gone if I write like this
var rateForPeriod = interestRate! / Double(100)
rateForPeriod = rateForPeriod / Double(K.monthsEachYear)

Is it correct way to fix this?

Comment: Try like this way `(interestRate! / Double(100)) / Double(K.monthsEachYear)`

Answer (score 1):

**Congratulations!**
You may have just found a bug in the compiler!

Let's try a few variations of your code:

This fails:

```
let optional: Double? = 1
let result = optional! / Double(1) / Double(1)
```

This works:

```
let optional: Double? = 1
let unwrapped = optional!
let result = unwrapped / Double(1) / Double(1)
```

This fails:

```
let rateForPeriod = (Double(1) as Double?)! / Double(1) / Double(1)
```

But this works:

```
let rateForPeriod = ((Double(1) as Double?)! as Double) / Double(1) / Double(1)
```

So this works too:

```
let optional: Double? = 1
let rateForPeriod = optional! as Double / Double(1) / Double(1)
```

That seems to be a side effect (probably bug) of the new optional unwrapping rules.

Note that doing only one division at a time works as expected:

```
let optional: Double? = 1
let rateForYear = optional! / Double(1)
let rateForPeriod = rateForYear / Double(1)
```

---

**What should we do?**

- File a bug report
- Stop force unwrapping things

Try to see if you can make interestRate not be an optional, use a guard clause or give it a default value like this: `let rate = interestRate ?? 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use **optional binding** to check whether **interestRate** is **nil** or not.

```
let interestRate: Double? = 0.4

if let interestRate = interestRate {
  let rateForPeriod = interestRate / Double(100) / Double(1)
}
```